# windows service cannot read app.config C#

Tags: c#, windows-services, app-config

I have created a windows service and there is an app.config that goes with it. After using the InstallUtil utility my service has installed and in the directory of the service it has correctly transformed the app.config file into the servicename.config file. When I check the file the AppSettings have all the keys that I expect. In my code I have the following line essentially in the OnStart event:

```
string timeToRun = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RunTime"];
```

In the windows event viewer it tells me the exception was thrown due to System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException

Comment: Just to be clear it's named servicename.exe.config, right?

Comment: Show, or rather, research the actual exception. It's not like "Oh no you can't read AppSettings from a Windows Service". Probably something to do with the transformation.

Comment: @CodeCaster....You dont have to be flippant. I know a windows service should be able to read from a windows service. if I change my code and replace the line to set timeToRun to be "17:20:00" the service runs.

Comment: @Volkan Paksoy...Yes the transformation seems to have worked fine during the install process

Comment: @bilpor: Does the exception have an inner exception that provides more detailed information? With only the information in the question it's hard to say something as everything looks in order

Comment: No it's proving impossible to debug the windows service. I have set debugging symbols on and I have attempted to attach to the process. VS attaches but doesn't break in any of the code. I only have the error from the default eventlog to go on.

Comment: I am also get ConfigurationErrorsException. I do Copy all values from App.Config and Delete App.config recreate and paste it. That works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea why as we have other windows services using an appSetings from the config file in the same way as above and it works. For this application doing the following seems to do the trick:

```
Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
AppSettingsSection appSettings = configuration.AppSettings;    
string timeToRun = appSettings.Settings["RunTime"].Value;
```

Comment: Tried a few solutions and this was the only one that worked for me.